# Unexpected behavior when implementing SpriteKit tap handler in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I ran into an issue when converting Objective-C code to Swift. I am added two sprites to an SKScene subclass. The first sprite is added directly to the scene and the second sprite is a child of the first node. When I tap on either sprite, the game should log the name of the sprite. This works as expected in the Objective-C version, but the Swift version logs "sprite1" no matter which node I tap on.

**Objective-C**

Declare sprites and add them to the scene

```
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(32, 32);
    SKSpriteNode *sprite1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:size];
    sprite1.name = @"sprite1";
    sprite1.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    [self addChild:sprite1];

    SKSpriteNode *sprite2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:size];
    sprite2.name = @"sprite2";
    sprite2.position = CGPointMake(150, 100);
    [sprite1 addChild:sprite2];
```

Touch handler

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"sprite2"]) {
            NSLog(@"sprite2");
        }
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"sprite1"]) {
            NSLog(@"sprite1");
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift**

Declare sprites and add them to the scene

```
    let size = CGSizeMake(32, 32)
    let sprite1 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: size)
    sprite1.name = "sprite1"
    sprite1.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)

    self.addChild(sprite1)

    let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: size)
    sprite2.name = "sprite1"
    sprite2.position = CGPointMake(150, 100)

    sprite1.addChild(sprite2)
```

Touch handler

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if (node.name == "sprite2") {
            println("sprite2")
        }
        if (node.name == "sprite1") {
            println("sprite1")
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `sprite2.name` to "sprite1."

```
let size = CGSizeMake(32, 32)
    let sprite1 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: size)
    sprite1.name = "sprite1"
    sprite1.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)

    self.addChild(sprite1)

    let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: size)
    sprite2.name = "sprite1"  //here
    sprite2.position = CGPointMake(150, 100)

    sprite1.addChild(sprite2)
```

Change it to "sprite2."

```
let size = CGSizeMake(32, 32)
    let sprite1 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: size)
    sprite1.name = "sprite1"
    sprite1.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)

    self.addChild(sprite1)

    let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: size)
    sprite2.name = "sprite2"
    sprite2.position = CGPointMake(150, 100)

    sprite1.addChild(sprite2)
```